# Nested array issue in meta_query

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, meta-query

I am using following meta_query to search blog post according to following search criteria,

search logic :

1. if expire date set, check the expiry of the post, otherwise just include it
2. if country(`$_country`) in the filters, search for that particular country with above expire date rule. otherwise just apply the expire date rule.

meta_query:

```
$expire_meta_1 = array(
    'key' => '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_3_fieldID_7_numInSet_0',
    'value' => '',
    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
);

$expire_meta_2 = array(
    'key' => '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_3_fieldID_7_numInSet_0',
    'value' => date("Y-m-d"),
    'compare' => '>=',
    'type' => 'DATE'
);

if($_country!=''){
    $country_meta = array(
        'key' => '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_3_fieldID_8_numInSet_0',
        'value' => $_country,
        'compare' => '='
    );
    $args['meta_query'] = array( 'relation' => 'AND', array( 'relation' => 'OR', $expire_meta_1, $expire_meta_2), $country_meta);
} else{
    $args['meta_query'] = array( 'relation' => 'OR', $expire_meta_1, $expire_meta_2);
}
```

the issue is, if it is country search, post should set the expire date. but I need to select the posts also not set the expire date.(if set check the expiry, that is anyway working).

But if I am not searching for specific country, the expire date rule(rule 1) is working properly.

Anybody have any idea what is my mistake. Any help would be appreciate. 
I hope question is clear, otherwise I can provide more details, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand what is the point of this condition `date is greater than or equal to todayDate OR date is not empty` it is just same as `date is greater than or equal to todayDate` isn't it ?

Comment: @Sumit the point is, in some post we are setting the expire date, but rest we doesn't set it. So whenever it sets we need to check the expiry rule, otherwise we can include that post regardless of expiry date as there is no expiry date set to post.

Comment: Okay so you mean if country is set then pull the posts (country AND expire) OR (No expire at all regardless of country)

Comment: sorry for the confusion, expire date set from post itself, then the country is from the filters in search. First the expire rule is, if expiry date set in the post, then check the expiry, otherwise post without expire dates should be in the search results. then the country filter, if there is country search for country plus expire rule which I describe avove

Comment: Okay thanks but in your question you are missing the relation between all three ? I guess you want `((country AND expiry) OR no expiry)` but you've `(country AND (expiry OR no expiry))` ? So if country is not there, then there is no mean of expire at all because you've placed AND as a relation.

Comment: The current above query will display the posts which have country then expiry or no expiry. Does it make sense ?

Comment: @Sumit thanks for help, anyway I need something like this `((country AND expiry) OR (country AND no_expiry) )` in first step, for now just forget the second step(I mean the else statement )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36899/discussion-between-janith-chinthana-and-sumit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the real issue after few hours of debugging.

I'm using `simple fields` to save the `expire date` and `country` values. So in `simple field` even we are not setting anything it is still save empty string in the database. So when I check the non existing fields, it is not giving correct results, however when I search of empty string(like below) it is giving me the correct output.

```
$expire_meta_1 = array(
    'key' => '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_3_fieldID_7_numInSet_0',
    'value' => '',
    'compare' => '='
);
```

I should thanks to @Sumit to help me to figure out the real issue.